# Fetch port from elastic search supervisord file

Tags: python

What is the best way to extract port number from the elastic search supervisord config file? Pasting config file content below for reference.

```
[supervisord]
logfile=/local/apps/supervisord.prod.log
pidfile=/local/apps/supervisord.prod.pid

[program:elasticsearch]
command=env JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/java/jdk11" ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms15G -Xmx15G" /data/myapp/lib/elasticsearch-5.0.1/bin/elasticsearch -E http.host=%(ENV_HOSTNAME)s -E http.port=11132 -E path.data=/local/apps/myapp/elasticdata -E path.logs=/local/apps/myapp/elasticlogs -E http.max_content_length=800mb
autorestart=true
autostart=true
priority=10
redirect_stderr=true
```

This is what I've tried but seems I am still stuck.

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('elastic_supervisord_config.conf')
config.get('program:elasticsearch', 'command', raw=True)
```

This returns me the following string

> 'env JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/java/jdk11" ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms15G -Xmx15G"
> /data/myapp/lib/elasticsearch-5.0.1/bin/elasticsearch -E
> http.host=%(ENV_HOSTNAME)s -E http.port=11132 -E
> path.data=/local/apps/myapp/elasticdata -E
> path.logs=/local/apps/myapp/elasticlogs -E
> http.max_content_length=800mb'

From the above string, now I want to fetch the value of 'http.port' i.e. 11132. I can definitely split and regex match but looking for some clean, less error prone solution.

Comment: I don't think there is a clean, less error prone solution. How is that supervisord.conf file generated, and why do you need to extract the port number from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without involving regular expressions you could extract the port like this:

```
val = config.get('program:elasticsearch', 'command', raw=True)
port = [t for t in val.split() if t.startswith('http.port')][0].split('=')[1]
```